# ajv addSchema and validate the data doesn't fail with intentional test to fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajv

I am using https://ajv.js.org/ to validate schemas and the configuration.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "things": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 0,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/thing"
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "thing": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "type",
        "label"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Thing name"
        },
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "THING1",
            "THING2",
            "THING3",
            "THING4"
          ],
          "description": "Thing type"
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "label to display for the thing"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The data to test is:

```
let data = {
  "things": [
     {
       "type": "THING1",
       "label": "Context navigate test"
     }
  ]
}
```

when running validate(data) it fails which is expected

```
[
  {
    instancePath: '/things/0',
    schemaPath: '#/definitions/thing/required',
    keyword: 'required',
    params: { missingProperty: 'name' },
    message: "must have required property 'name'"
  }
]
```

When I move the definitions to a file it doesn't fail anymore.
Definition now in a file
directory /definitions/thing_schema.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "definitions/thing_schema.json#/thing",
  "definitions": {
    "thing": {
      "description": "A representation of a thing",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "type",
        "label"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Thing name"
        },
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "THING1",
            "THING2",
            "THING3",
            "THING4"
          ],
          "description": "Thing type"
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "label to display for the thing"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The schema is now referencing the file instead of referencing the definition in its own file.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "things": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 0,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "$ref": "definitions/thing_schema.json#/thing"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This time the validation doesn't fail.

```
ajv.addSchema(thingDefintionFile)
const validate = ajv.compile(schemaFile)
if(!validate(data)) {
    console.log(validate.errors)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it.

```
"$ref": "things#/definitions/thing"
```

and changing the file definition to

```
"$id": "things",
```

I didn't reference it correctly.